# Access a dir in client machine

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, applet

I'm developing a java web application (jsp-servlet) for my collage project.

If i brief you about the project..

I only have to **read the barcodes** from the scanned documents and **sort them according to particular order** and **store in the server** and **again show the sorted output in the jsp page**.

- To scan the documents there's a separate applet, and as an output of the scanner applet i get a temp_image folder. (I have to start the reading/decoding process right after the applet process.)
- To decode the barcodes i use a api call Zxing.

My issues are..

- I have to set-up this application in number of machines so, if i upload the temp_image files to server and decode there will a network traffic problem.
- I have no sense of accessing a dir in client machine from the server as well
- I've heard that it's not recommended to have several applets in the same web-application.
- At the same time if i use a applet i won't be able to store data in the server too.

I'm kind stuck with this matter.. since i'm new to java programming I'm not that much exposed to new technologies too.

***Please suggest me any new technology or efficient way to do this.***

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: An applet can always call services of the origin server. So if you have an applet which is able to scan the barcodes, why don't you decode the barcodes right away and send the decoded data directly to the server? Then you don't need to store the images on the client and no need to transfer the raw image data to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Web Applications are not allowed to access client's resources (file system) directly.

To access (upload) the barcodes from Client to Server machine you need to provide a Browse button, where user can select a saved barcode in png or jpeg format. You can then upload the image to your server using multipart file upload.

If you are planning to scan the barcode directly from the client's camera, then you need to include a flash plugin, [webcamjs](https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs) for example.

Comment: First of all thanks for the suggestion, 

As i have stated since i'm gonna use this in several machines and if i upload the images to the server, there will be a network block and that will effect to the performance of the application.

Anyway i'm using a scanner and i get jpegs as the output, i have to use those jpegs as the input to my reading process.

Comment: so is your "reading process" on server side or client side (javascript)?

Comment: i have to do it in the client side otherwise as i said process will get slow.. since i'm using a Java API to read barcodes (zxing) i can't go with JavaScript :/